# IE11 slow / freeze with AngularJS's ng-repeat rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, browser

Currently I have a very sublte problem to solve with IE11 and AngularJS.

My page consists of two nested ng-repeat to create a tabset with a table inside any tab.

Here the code: http://pastebin.com/0fffPz5Z

In the code, each application's object have around 1.000 item's related objects.
With a Chrome, Safari and Mozilla I have no problem, all is superfast! With IE11 the page go slow and IE11 show me the message of a too slow page's script....

I've created an IE11 interface's profiling with this result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5xuystxht6gjkr/IE11-interface-profiling.png?dl=0

Is this another IE11's bug??? Sorry for my English and thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Edit: Currently (for "debug" purpose) I removed all td's content... the IE11 is still too slow. :(

```
                <tabset ng-show="!applicationsLoading">
                <tab ng-repeat="application in applications track by application.name">
                    <tab-heading>
                        <em class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></em> {{ application.name }}
                    </tab-heading>
                    <div>
                        <!-- START table responsive-->
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="item in application.items track by item.itemid">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- Graph or History column -->
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END table responsive-->
                    </div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
```

Comment: Are you using AngularJS >= 1.3? Then have a look at one-time bindings `:: expression`. And what about paging? Nobody can view that much data...

Comment: I've edited my question. Without the td's {{ }} expression and other statements IE8 is still too slow.

Comment: Still you have 1000 elements. Try to make lazy load, pagination, etc. One more solution is to use reactjs for rendering

Comment: @nesteant Why Chrome, Safari and Firefox are SUPER fast and IE11 go too slow???

Comment: You should ask IE developers :)

Comment: I'm an engineer on the IE team. My suggestion is that you use one-way binding unless, for some reason, you need to have two-way binding. In the case of the latter, you should limit the number of live-bindings at any given time by filtering the on-screen elements - as stated by others, hundreds (or a thousand+) items in the document is almost *never* appropriate for a good user-experience. Basically, @nesteant's answer below is precisely what you should do :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AngularJs has limits for rendering bindings per page (In some articles you can find that it is around 2000 bindings). Currently you've just faced this situation. The reason why chrome and Mozilla work smoothly is that DOM operations for them are optimized better.
In order to improve your performance try to:

- avoid using sort in ng-repeat (sort it before insertions)
- Use one-time bindings (:: syntax)
- Remove unnecessary watches
- Optimize digest cycles
- Use pagination
- Replace angularjs ng-repeat with ReactJs components (in case of really big amount of data)

Comment: Another optimization is to minimize the number of updates to the angular model (e.g. when you are aggregation data of multiple endpoints, collect the data first and then assign it to your scope once)

Comment: I have heard using `ng-bind` instead of inner bindings (i.e. `{{ data }}`) also helps. Is this the case or is it unnecessary?

Comment: can you reference "some articles" you mentioned in your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this same problem. Had everything working perfectly on Chrome, then tested in IE and it kept crashing with anything over 1000 records.

I ended up following [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/3d274f0f-f47a-4bf0-91ec-8ebad479881b/entry/how_to_implement_a_table_with_lazy_loading_infinite_scroll_in_angularjs?lang=en) to add a "lazy load" or "infinite scroll" to my table. So on table load it still pulls all 1000+ records, but instead of loading this data directly into the table, I load it into a big array, then just subset my table of say 50 records. Then create a directive that listens to the scroll on the table, and when it's near the bottom then fire off a function which just adds the next 50 records from the big array into my table array. Here's a direct [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyvw31s3/215/) from the link above.

**HTML**

```
<tbody when-scroll-ends="loadMoreRecords()">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableData">
        <td>{{row.attribute}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Module**

```
angular.module(myApp, []).directive('whenScrollEnds', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var processingScroll = false;

            var visibleHeight = element.height();
            var threshold = 200;

            element.scroll(function () {
                var scrollableHeight = element.prop('scrollHeight');
                var hiddenContentHeight = scrollableHeight - visibleHeight;

                if (hiddenContentHeight - element.scrollTop() <= threshold) {
                    // Scroll is almost at the bottom. Loading more rows
                    scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrollEnds);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
function loadTableData() {
    LoadDataService().getData().then(function(response) {
        fullTableList = response.data;
        $scope.tableData = fullTableList.slice(0,50);
    });
}

function loadMoreRecords() {
    // if there's still more than 20 records left, add the next chunk of 20
    if (fullTableList.length - $scope.tableData.length > 20) {
        $scope.tableData = $scope.tableData.concat(fullTableList.slice($scope.tableData.length,$scope.tableData.length + 20));
    } else {
        while ($scope.tableData.length < fullTableList.length) {
            $scope.tableData.push(fullTableList[$scope.tableData.length]);
        }
    }
}
```