# Fields not editable in IE 11

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, internet-explorer-11

I have an angular web application. When run it on Chrome and FireFox it works like a charm, but when I test it on IE 11, after a while all my **inputs**(type=text) and **textareas** aren't editable. If I edit the textarea from the inspector and asign the attribute **maxlength** it works. The time is random, I don't have any errors in my console log. I have searched for some answers and didn't find much beside Microsoft IE11 Install Fixes. Any advice ?

```
 <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <h2 ng-bind="someVar"></h2>
   <input type="text">
   <textarea></textarea>
 </div>

    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.someVar = 'Angular works';
    }]);
```

Comment: Some code will be useful.

Comment: @VladRadulescu Have you been able to figure out why it happend? I observe the same problem in my angular application.

Comment: @Dominik I think it's an angular version issue, because this bug didn't reproduce on versions higher then 1.3.6. What version are you using ?

Comment: @VladRadulescu We are using 1.5.6, so bad news for me. We are doing lot of $http requests, maybe angular is messing up something. When the textarea is not editable and I cause another $http request to complete then the textarea is instantly editable!

Comment: @Dominik Well, if you are using 1.5.6 I doubt it's an angular issue for IE 11, maybe a css solution.

Comment: @VladRadulescu I fixed the problem now, it was caused by too many ng-repeat bindings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443986/ie11-slow-freeze-with-angularjss-ng-repeat-rendering

Comment: @Dominik Thanks for the reply.