# Selenium IE WebDriver .NET Timeout when waiting for element to be clickable

Tags: .net, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, timeout, internet-explorer-11

I'm using the IE WebDriver to test an AngularJS web application. The problem occures when I execute the tests on a TFS build server. There is a html textarea element where I want to insert some text. But first I'm waiting for the element to be clickable. Sometimes it works, but mostly the Driver throws a timeout exception.

I tried scrolling to the elements position before I wait for the element to be clickable, but didn't help.

Not having this problem with pure MVC pages. Are there any problems when the element is contained within a external .html file which is loaded by angular using ng-include? The element can be "found" and I can see it by the way, so it's obviously there. When I use my mouse and keyboard I can insert text without any problems.

---

```
    public void EnterText(string elementId, string text)
    {
        this.Driver.WaitUntil(_ => this.Driver.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
        this.Driver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id(elementId)));

        var element = this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId));
        this.Driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

        element = this.Driver.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(elementId)));

        element.Clear();
        element.SendKeys(text);
    }
```

---

*Selenium/WebDriver Version: 2.48.0
AngularJS Version: 1.5.6
.NET Framework: 4.5*

---

**EDIT:**

The selenium test actually covered a problem in my application! There were nested and inefficient ng-repeat statements which caused internet explorer to slow down dramatically so it couldn't handle the inputs. Sometimes it took over a minute to recover, thats why even the long waits didn't help.
See [IE11 slow / freeze with AngularJS's ng-repeat rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443986/ie11-slow-freeze-with-angularjss-ng-repeat-rendering)

Comment: Share your tried attempt with code and textarea HTML as well...:)

Comment: And if you want to enter text into textarea then why are you waiting for clickable instead of visible???

Comment: At some point the element can be read-only and after enabling i want to wait before i enter some text :)

Comment: Ok but as you are saying sometime work and sometime not, then it must be timing issue, you need to increase time...:)

Comment: 20 seconds is not enough? I can edit the textarea manually within these 20s..

Comment: It's hard to say when textarea getting visible. may be sometime it's visible within given time or may be not, and if your code works well sometime then possible given time may not be enough..

Comment: Actually your coding approach is not good, there is no need scroll to the element and no need to wait for element again an again with certain condition, try provided answer, hope it helps..:)