# Difference with use of using Select as in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, angularjs-ng-options

Select box in IE is causing a problem in the opening for the first time when used with 
`identity as identity.identityName for identity in identityProofList track by identity.identityId` or `ng-repeat`
but when used without `identity as`, it is working fine and can not see any difference in the functionality of select box also.

```
<select name="identityProof" ng-model="identityProof" ng-change="changeProofOfIdentity(identityProof)" ng-options="identity.identityName for identity in identityProofList track by identity.identityId"  id="identityProofList" >
```

Where identityProofList is array of objects having properties identityName and identityId.

1. What is difference b/w the both?
2. Why `ng-repeat` is causing problem with IE11.

Comment: Look at [IE11 slow / freeze with AngularJS's ng-repeat rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443986/ie11-slow-freeze-with-angularjss-ng-repeat-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

> What is difference b/w the both?

Do you mean the difference between [ng-repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp) and [ng-options](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-options.asp)?

The difference between using them to create DropdownList is that:

Dropdowns made with ng-options allows the selected value to be an object, while dropdowns made from ng-repeat has to be a string.

More details, check the [AngularJS Select Boxes](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_select.asp).

> Why ng-repeat is causing problem with IE11 is also with using .

According to your codes, I create a sample using the following code, it works well on my IE browser (11.17134.1.0), you could refer to it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Select a identity:</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedidentity">
        <option ng-repeat="x in identityProofList " value="{{x.identityId}}">{{x.identityName}}</option>
    </select>
    <h1>You selected: {{selectedidentity}}</h1><br />

    <select name="identityProof" ng-model="identityProof" ng-change="changeProofOfIdentity(identityProof)"
            ng-options="identity as identity.identityName for identity in identityProofList track by identity.identityId"
            id="identityProofList"></select>
    <h1>You selected: {{selectedvalue}}</h1>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.identityProofList = [
            { identityId: "1001", identityName: "Admin" },
            { identityId: "1002", identityName: "User" },
            { identityId: "1003", identityName: "Customer" }
        ];
        $scope.selectedvalue = "";
        $scope.changeProofOfIdentity = function (identity) {
            $scope.selectedvalue = identity.identityName;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAbKi.gif).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was asking for difference b/w using 'select as' syntax and without it because the latter one is working fine with IE and former one is not i.e. `identity as identity.identityName for identity in identityProofList track by identity.identityId`  & `identity.identityName for identity in identityProofList track by identity.identityId` , and ng-repeat is also not working with IE, but I know the difference b/w both